# Find hidden substrings in original string?

Tags: python, string

Hi have a string such as this:

```
orig = "hbeojllok"
```

And would like to know if there is a specific hidden substring in this string. For example, we can find the word 'hello' in it: **h**b**e**oj**llo**k. We can also find the word 'book': h**b**e**o**jll**ok**. The only constraint is that the letters of the hidden substring have to be in the correct order in the original string. How would I implement this in python? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at distance algorithms yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No sorry. I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: I would probably do this by obtaining a list of words (such as that found at `/usr/share/dict/words`on ubuntu) and run tests on them one by one, returning ones that match...

Answer (score 2):

Loop through each letter in the word you're searching for and look for that letter in the original string, starting from the last letter found. Return the result when a letter isn't found or when there are no more letters to look for.

```
def f(orig, word):
    idx = 0
    for letter in word:
        x = orig.find(letter, idx)
        if x != -1:
            idx = x
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I had expected this to be slower than the regex approach: `re.search('.*'.join(word), orig) is not None` … but it's actually faster. +1